# Typescript default input element in state

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a activeField state where its just empty when first launched but when user focus on the field it gets added to the state. Typescript is throwing an warning because when I want to update the selectionEnd of that field its saying `Property 'selectionEnd' does not exist on type 'string'.`
Which makes sense but what would I set the default state to if I don;t have the input until the user focuses.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   state = {
      activefield: "",
      type: "",
      loaded: false,
   };
   
   onUpdate = () => {
    const { activefield } = this.state;
   // typescript warning. selectionEnd of that field its saying `Property 'selectionEnd
    activefield.selectionEnd = 0;
   }

   onFocusField = () => {
     const { target } = event;
     this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value,
    });
   }

   render() {
     ....
   }
}
```

I'd like to not have to pass **any** as a type to it if possible.

Comment: the type of `activefield` (I suggest you change this to `activeField` for clarity) is string, and strings don't have any custom properties. maybe you want to set it to `state = { activeField: {} }`?

Comment: If you just want to bypass the warning: `(activefield as any).selectionEnd = 0;`

Comment: How is onFocusField used? Is that an onFocus handler?

Comment: Thanks all. I'd like to stay away from using any if possible but that's a neat way of been able to typecast with the () around it. As far as onFocusField yes its a input handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
  state: {
    activefield: HTMLInputElement | null,
    type: string,
    loaded: boolean
  } = {
     activefield: null,
     type: "",
     loaded: false,
  };

  // or alternatively like that

  state = {
     activefield: null as HTMLInputElement | null,
     type: "",
     loaded: false,
  };
  
  onUpdate = () => {
   const { activefield } = this.state;

   if (activefield) {
     activefield.selectionEnd = 0;
   }
  }
```

It requires you to explicitly provide interface for state, but at the same time allows you to properly type `activeField`

Comment: What does null as HTMLInputElement | null mean ?

Comment: @me-me type assertion. You basically say to compiler "this field can be HTMLInputElement or null" More info: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion

Comment: I understand the or null part. But this part if weird to me. Typecasting null as a null as HTMLInputElement never seen that before.